# Square root of an Identity + Nilpotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Define $N \in L(F^5)$ by $N(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5) = (2x_2, 3x_3, -x_4, 4x_5,0).$

Find $\sqrt(I+N)$

For F, this is the matrix representation that I have found:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 &-1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

In Axler's Linear Algebra done right, he explains a process of using the Taylor series of $\sqrt(1+x)$ to find coefficients to find square root of this matrix N + the identity, but I didn't understand what the process was.

Can anyone explain how to find square roots of matrices in general or point to some resources that provide more detail?

Comment: Plug $N$ into the Taylor series for $\sqrt{1+x}$.

Comment: But how do we find the values of the coefficients then?

Comment: If you know what a Taylor series is then you know how to compute the coefficients of the Taylor series (specifically around $x=0$). If you don't know what a Taylor series is then you need to look it up.

Comment: More specifically, plug $N$ into the Taylor series for $\sqrt{1+x}$ and note that this is actually a **finite** series because all fifth or higher order terms vanish owing to the nilpotence of $N$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the square root of $I+N$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215595/how-do-i-find-the-square-root-of-in)